# Gradle Compilation Errors when adding 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.+'

Tags: android, gradle, amazon-s3, google-play-services, aws-sdk

I am running Android Studio, and my app has been running perfectly until I added the following dependencies to my gradle file:

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.+
```

These caused the following warnings when rebuilding the project:

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlh accesses a declared method 'getInstance()' dynamically
  Maybe this is program method 'android.support.design.widget.SnackbarManager { android.support.design.widget.SnackbarManager getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'android.support.v4.content.SharedPreferencesCompat$EditorCompat { android.support.v4.content.SharedPreferencesCompat$EditorCompat getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'android.support.v4.text.BidiFormatter { android.support.v4.text.BidiFormatter getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'android.support.v7.app.TwilightCalculator { android.support.v7.app.TwilightCalculator getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.metrics.MetricCollector$Factory { com.amazonaws.metrics.MetricCollector getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.transform.CredentialsJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.transform.CredentialsJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.transform.GetCredentialsForIdentityResultJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.transform.GetCredentialsForIdentityResultJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.transform.GetIdResultJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.transform.GetIdResultJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.transform.GetOpenIdTokenResultJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.transform.GetOpenIdTokenResultJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitosync.model.transform.DatasetJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.cognitosync.model.transform.DatasetJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitosync.model.transform.DeleteDatasetResultJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.cognitosync.model.transform.DeleteDatasetResultJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitosync.model.transform.DescribeDatasetResultJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.cognitosync.model.transform.DescribeDatasetResultJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitosync.model.transform.ListDatasetsResultJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.cognitosync.model.transform.ListDatasetsResultJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitosync.model.transform.ListRecordsResultJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.cognitosync.model.transform.ListRecordsResultJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitosync.model.transform.RecordJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.cognitosync.model.transform.RecordJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitosync.model.transform.RegisterDeviceResultJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.cognitosync.model.transform.RegisterDeviceResultJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitosync.model.transform.SubscribeToDatasetResultJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.cognitosync.model.transform.SubscribeToDatasetResultJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitosync.model.transform.UnsubscribeFromDatasetResultJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.cognitosync.model.transform.UnsubscribeFromDatasetResultJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.cognitosync.model.transform.UpdateRecordsResultJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.cognitosync.model.transform.UpdateRecordsResultJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.AttributeDefinitionJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.AttributeDefinitionJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.AttributeValueJsonMarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.AttributeValueJsonMarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.AttributeValueJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.AttributeValueJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.BatchGetItemResultJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.BatchGetItemResultJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.BatchWriteItemResultJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.BatchWriteItemResultJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.CapacityJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.CapacityJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.ConsumedCapacityJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.ConsumedCapacityJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.CreateTableResultJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.CreateTableResultJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.DeleteItemResultJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.DeleteItemResultJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.DeleteRequestJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.DeleteRequestJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.DeleteTableResultJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.DeleteTableResultJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.DescribeTableResultJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.DescribeTableResultJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.GetItemResultJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.GetItemResultJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.GlobalSecondaryIndexDescriptionJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.GlobalSecondaryIndexDescriptionJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.ItemCollectionMetricsJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.ItemCollectionMetricsJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.KeySchemaElementJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.KeySchemaElementJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.KeysAndAttributesJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.KeysAndAttributesJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.ListTablesResultJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.ListTablesResultJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.LocalSecondaryIndexDescriptionJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.LocalSecondaryIndexDescriptionJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.ProjectionJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.ProjectionJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.ProvisionedThroughputDescriptionJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.ProvisionedThroughputDescriptionJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.PutItemResultJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.PutItemResultJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.PutRequestJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.PutRequestJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.QueryResultJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.QueryResultJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.ScanResultJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.ScanResultJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.StreamSpecificationJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.StreamSpecificationJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.TableDescriptionJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.TableDescriptionJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.UpdateItemResultJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.UpdateItemResultJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.UpdateTableResultJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.UpdateTableResultJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.WriteRequestJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.transform.WriteRequestJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.s3.util.Mimetypes { com.amazonaws.services.s3.util.Mimetypes getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.transform.AssumeRoleResultStaxUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.transform.AssumeRoleResultStaxUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.transform.AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResultStaxUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.transform.AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResultStaxUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.transform.AssumedRoleUserStaxUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.transform.AssumedRoleUserStaxUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.transform.CredentialsStaxUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.transform.CredentialsStaxUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.transform.FederatedUserStaxUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.transform.FederatedUserStaxUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.transform.GetFederationTokenResultStaxUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.transform.GetFederationTokenResultStaxUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.transform.GetSessionTokenResultStaxUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.transform.GetSessionTokenResultStaxUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeJsonUnmarshallers$BigDecimalJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeJsonUnmarshallers$BigDecimalJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeJsonUnmarshallers$BigIntegerJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeJsonUnmarshallers$BigIntegerJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeJsonUnmarshallers$BooleanJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeJsonUnmarshallers$BooleanJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeJsonUnmarshallers$ByteBufferJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeJsonUnmarshallers$ByteBufferJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeJsonUnmarshallers$ByteJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeJsonUnmarshallers$ByteJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeJsonUnmarshallers$DateJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeJsonUnmarshallers$DateJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeJsonUnmarshallers$DoubleJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeJsonUnmarshallers$DoubleJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeJsonUnmarshallers$FloatJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeJsonUnmarshallers$FloatJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeJsonUnmarshallers$IntegerJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeJsonUnmarshallers$IntegerJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeJsonUnmarshallers$LongJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeJsonUnmarshallers$LongJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeJsonUnmarshallers$StringJsonUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeJsonUnmarshallers$StringJsonUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeStaxUnmarshallers$BigDecimalStaxUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeStaxUnmarshallers$BigDecimalStaxUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeStaxUnmarshallers$BigIntegerStaxUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeStaxUnmarshallers$BigIntegerStaxUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeStaxUnmarshallers$BooleanStaxUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeStaxUnmarshallers$BooleanStaxUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeStaxUnmarshallers$ByteBufferStaxUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeStaxUnmarshallers$ByteBufferStaxUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeStaxUnmarshallers$ByteStaxUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeStaxUnmarshallers$ByteStaxUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeStaxUnmarshallers$DateStaxUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeStaxUnmarshallers$DateStaxUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
  Maybe this is program method 'com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeStaxUnmarshallers$DoubleStaxUnmarshaller { com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeStaxUnmarshallers$DoubleStaxUnmarshaller getInstance(); }'
Preparing output jar [F:\IcyGo-v2.6\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar]


Copying resources from program jar [F:\IcyGo-v2.6\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar]
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseUtf8(ConstantPoolParser.java:371)
    at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse0(ConstantPoolParser.java:262)
    at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse0(ConstantPoolParser.java:323)
    at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse0(ConstantPoolParser.java:309)
    at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse(ConstantPoolParser.java:150)
    at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseIfNecessary(ConstantPoolParser.java:124)
    at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.getPool(ConstantPoolParser.java:115)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:482)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:569)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:366)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
```

And here is my complete gradle.build file (app level):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "31.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':swipelistview')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.0.0'
    compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.orangegangsters:swipy:1.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:7.5.0'

    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.+'
}
```

I think the issue is due to using `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`, as in the demo project they used `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'`, and that demo project is running perfectly.

Thing is, I cannot downgrade my app to use `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'`.

Any suggestions or help is highly appreciated in this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to god, I ultimately found the solution. The cause behind the error was `GC overhead limit exceeded` Amazon AWS library contains a huge number of methods, that causes `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` while compiling.
The solution is to add

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

and

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion 15//use any version as needed by you
    targetSdkVersion 23//use any version as needed by you
    versionCode 1//your own version code
    versionName "1.0"//your own versionName
    multiDexEnabled true//required


}
```

this to your app level build.gradle file.